# Can I draw this diagram in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I need to draw this (likely very simple) diagram shown in the image but I've never used Tikz before.

[image: diagram]

My problem is basiclly how to draw these vertical dotted lines and mainly arrange the math in blocks like this with these arrows pointing from one to the other - of course I have no problem writing the math, the needed structure is giving me problems. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

So far I was able to do this. I feel I'm almost there, but having problems with alignments. Any help?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}]

%Draw dashed lines
\draw  [dashed] (2.5,0) -- (2.5,2);
\draw  [dashed] (5,0) -- (5,2);
\draw  [dashed] (7.5,0) -- (7.5,2);

%Draw nodes of equations
\node at (1.25,1) [square,inner sep=-1.3em, draw] {
    $\begin{aligned}
     \vert \Psi \rangle &= \sum_{i}{c_i \vert a_i \rangle},\\
     &\sum_{i}{\vert a_i \rangle \langle a_i \vert} = \mathds{1}
    \end{aligned}$

};
\node at (3.75,1) [square,inner sep=-1.3em, draw] {};
\node at (6.25,1) [square,inner sep=-1.3em, draw] {};

%Draw title nodes

\node at (1.25,2) [square,inner sep=-1.3em, draw] {$\left( \mathcal{H}, \langle \cdot \vert \cdot \rangle \right)$};
\node at (3.75,2) [square,inner sep=-1.3em, draw] {$\left( \mathcal{H}_{Phys}, \langle \cdot \vert \cdot \rangle _{\eta _{+}} \right)$};
\node at (6.25,2) [square,inner sep=-1.3em, draw] {$\left( \mathcal{H}, \langle \cdot \vert \cdot \rangle \right)$};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also I don't know if this is a good approach to do what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). This isn't a "Please do my work for me" site! What do you have so far? Try to create ... It would help if you could just add the formula.

Comment: You could use a `matrix of math nodes` from `tikz`. For details see section 57.1 of the tikz manual or search for examples on TeX.SX!

Comment: Alright, I'm trying to work something out. Anything I'll post here. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `arydshln` and a couple of tricks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,braket,rsfso,arydshln}

\newcommand{\blank}{{\,{\cdot}\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{0.5em}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c:c@{}c:c@{}}
% first column
\begin{gathered}[t]
(\mathcal{H},\braket{\blank|\blank}) \\
\ket{\psi}=\sum_i c_i\ket{a_i} \\
\sum_i \lvert a_i\times a_i\rvert = 1
\end{gathered}
&\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-2\normalbaselineskip}{$\:\longrightarrow$}}&
%second column
\begin{gathered}[t]
(\mathcal{H}_{\rho hy},\braket{\blank|\blank}_{\eta_+}) \\
\begin{aligned}
\ket{\psi}  &\to \ket{\psi'}=\sum_i c_i\rho^{-1}\ket{a_i} \\
\ket{\psi'} &\to \ket{\psi'(t)}=e^{-iHt/\hbar}\ket{\psi'}
\end{aligned}
\end{gathered}
&\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-2\normalbaselineskip}{$\:\longrightarrow$}}&
% third column
\begin{gathered}[t]
(\mathcal{H},\braket{\blank|\blank}) \\
\begin{aligned}
& \ket{\psi'} \to \ket{\psi(t)} = \rho\ket{\psi'(t)} \\
& \quad = \rho e^{-iHt/\hbar}\ket{\psi'} \\
& \quad = \rho e^{-iHt/\hbar}\rho^{-1}\ket{\psi} \\
& \quad = e^{-iHt/\hbar}\ket{\psi}
\end{aligned}
\end{gathered}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]